# SMTP function is not working and the execution time is exceeding

Tags: php, smtp, mail-sender

I want to have a PHPMailer and I use smtp, at home it is working perfectly, but at my office, is not working anymore because I receive the following error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUQ7b.jpg

I would like to know where does this error come from and how can I fix it?

I tried to increase the maximum execution time but after that time spend, I get the same error.

Comment: Perhaps your office is using firewalls / blocking ports / doing other stuff? If it's working in one place, but not another, it implies a difference in networks. Are you using a personal SMTP server? Or a hosted one?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look over the firewalls and come back.

Comment: In addition to Jonnix comment, also make sure the network is not having a proxy setting cos i also encountered something similar at a time

Comment: @Jonnix I was looking to open ports, I managed to do it from Windows Firewall but is still not working, is there other possible cause?

Comment: Changing Windows Firewall for your local machine doesn't change any rules on the network you're on. So basically there are lots of possible options. You also haven't told us where this SMTP server is, so we can't really help much.